# Sub Query is not working in SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Delete from TableName where id in (select id from TableName order by id LIMIT 1);

I tried to execute this query in the DatabaseHelper like ,Its executing without error but the row is not deleting from SQLite table.

```html
sdb.rawQuery("Delete from TableName where id in (select id from TableName order by id LIMIT 1)",
     null);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sdb.delete()` instead? It will return you the deleted row or 0 if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rawQuery()` won't execute other than SELECT **queries**.
For **commands** (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ...), use `execSQL()`.

Comment: Well, you can also use the delete() method (or insert() or update()) in many cases. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)

Comment: @larsh Yes, you can. But I like to deal with SQL directly, rather than indirectly (I've grown up with that kind of syntax, some decades ago)